# How can I Integrate Relay Subscription with GraphQl Lighthouse Subscription?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, graphql, relayjs

I am working on a sample chatting app, I am developing both server and client side.
Firstly I have developed its restful APIs and integrated them with the Front-End, then I have made the GraphQl APIs. They are working except the subscription.
I am not sure where the issue  is. (Back-End or Front-End)

I had followed the lighthouse docs for making the subscription and integrating it with relay
https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#setup
https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#defining-fields
https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#trigger-subscriptions
https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#filtering-subscriptions
https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#client-implementations

Then i completed the integration with relay docs
https://relay.dev/docs/en/subscriptions

Comment: each time i send message from the client side i get no response
I cheked pusher debug console, no actions found

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While it's good that you've consulted the documentation, getting an answer requires more information about your code and problem. Have a read about [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You'll get better, faster help if you help people understand your problem.